# Laravel Queues/Horizon - Distribute jobs evenly across multiple worker servers

Tags: php, laravel, redis, queue

**Overview**

I have a Laravel 9.x application which has a multiple different job classes that run on Horizon. These jobs are very resource intensive and so I am exploring different approaches on to how to scale my queue worker force **horizontally**. Currently, I have 3 dedicated worker servers that run Horizon and are all connected to the same central Redis instance to poll for jobs.

**My Problem**

Say I have a job class called `ProcessDocumentJob`. I also have 3 instances of Horizon running per my 3 worker servers. All 3 worker servers are listening to the same queue, `document-processing`. My issue is that if I where to dispatch the `ProcessDocumentJob` 3 times to the `document-processing` queue, there is no guarantee that all 3 of my worker servers would be utilized for maximum performance. What happens most of the time is **one** of the three worker servers picks up all three jobs and tries to process them while the other two worker servers are idle. What I would like to happen is for the jobs to be distributed evenly (*load balanced via a round robin approach*) across all my worker servers.

**My Current Solution**

My current solution to distribute jobs evenly across my worker servers is to set a `WORKER_QUEUE` env var specific to each server. So for my 3 worker servers there would be 3 different queues I would deploy the `ProcessDocumentJob` to (*worker-queue-1, worker-queue-2, worker-queue-3*). Additionally, I'm also using the `HORIZON_ENV` env var (*set to "worker"*) to specify the correct environment.

Here's a snippet of what my horizon.php config file looks like for this:

```php
'environments' => [
        'worker' => [
            'worker-supervisor' => [
                'connection' => 'redis',
                'queue' => [env('WORKER_QUEUE')],
                'balance' => 'simple',
                'maxProcesses' => 10,
                'maxJobs' => 0,
                'memory' => 512,
                'tries' => 3,
                'nice' => 0,
                'timeout' => 600,
            ],
        ],
```

The constructor of my `ProcessDocumentJob` job class looks like this:

```php
public function __construct(Document $document)
{
    $this->onQueue(Worker::bestPick());

    $this->document = $document;
}
```

The `Worker::bestPick()` method is my approach to a round robin equivalent of dispatching jobs. It knows how many worker servers are available, each worker server's corresponding queue name and which queue was last used so that when another `ProcessDocumentJob` job comes in, it knows which server worker queue is next in the chain to assign it too.

**The Drawback**

This solution works well for the most part and all my jobs are distributed evenly across my worker servers. However, if one of my three worker servers goes down, this solution would not work unless I implemented some sort of uptime check into my `Worker::bestPick()` method.

Additionally, I've also explored Redis's atomic locks and limiting the `maxJobs` field in my config file in an attempt to achieve what I'm after but had no success.

**Questions**

- How do I distribute jobs **evenly** across all my worker servers similar to how a load balancer would distribute traffic via Round Robin to web servers?
- Am I on the right path with attempting to **horizontally scale** my worker servers **with peak performance in mind**? Or is there a more *Laravel friendly* way of handling this?

**And yes, I know these things**

- Queue systems are first-in, first-out.
- The `balance` field can be set to "simple", "auto" and "false" and these values do not appear to help solve my problem.
- Yes, I've read the Laravel docs on Horizon and Queues.

**TL;DR**

I get that time is money... but don't be lazy. Read the whole thing ^

Comment: If you want each server to pull only one job at a time, have you tried setting `'maxProcesses' => 1`?

Comment: So yes, in theory that would distribute jobs evenly but not allow for concurrent processing since each server would only be process one job at a time, which would become an issue.

Comment: @DenisPriebe Did you come to any conclusions? Currently exploring exactly the same thing! :)

Comment: @Keipi Not really, still using the current solution I mentioned above with some modifications. In short, Horizon has a `WorkloadRepository` class and calling the `->get()` method on it will return a list of all active, running queues, their names, status, etc. Using this list I can determine which queues are operational and keep track of which queues last received a job (ie. my round robin approach.). Let me know if you want me to post my code as an answer...and I can show you exactly how I am doing this.

Comment: @DenisPriebe please post your approach, I am looking for something similar. I want to measure "capacity" of my servers and track results for previous jobs (cpu/mem) to make a predictive distribution approach that will take into account estimated resources, available resources and pick a best server

Comment: @Dmitry I posted my answer for you. Let me know if you have any questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is my current solution to the problem I described. In short, I have Worker class which is responsible for determining what queue/worker should receive the next job:

```
<?php

namespace App\Domain\Docs\Pdf\Worker;

use Exception;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Laravel\Horizon\Contracts\WorkloadRepository;
use Throwable;

class Worker
{
    /**
     * Get a list of all available, running "worker" queues in Horizon.
     */
    public static function queues(): array
    {
        $horizonWorkload = app(WorkloadRepository::class);

        try {
            $queues = $horizonWorkload->get();
        } catch (Exception|Throwable $exception) {
            $queues = [];
        }

        // Target all queues with this prefix...
        $prefix = 'worker-';

        return collect($queues)
            ->filter(fn (array $queue) => Str::startsWith($queue['name'], $prefix))
            ->sortBy('name')
            ->values()
            ->toArray();
    }

    /**
     * Determines the next worker that should receive a job.
     *
     * This current implementation uses the round-robin approach which keeps track
     * of the last worker that received a job and returns the name of the next
     * worker that is in line for the next job.
     */
    public static function bestPick(): string
    {
        $workers = static::queues();

        foreach ($workers as $key => $worker) {
            if ($worker['name'] === Cache::get('last-worker-used')) {
                if (array_key_exists(($key + 1), $workers)) {
                    Cache::put('last-worker-used', $workers[($key + 1)]['name'], now()->addMonth());

                    return $workers[($key + 1)]['name'];
                }
            }
        }

        $fallbackWorker = Arr::get($workers, '0.name', 'worker-1');

        Cache::put('last-worker-used', $fallbackWorker, now()->addMonth());

        return $fallbackWorker;
    }
}
```

Then in your job(s) class you can do the following:

```
<?php

namespace App\Domain\Docs\Pdf\Energizer;

use App\Domain\Docs\Pdf\Worker\Worker;
use App\Models\Pdf\Pdf;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class ProcessPdfJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable;
    use InteractsWithQueue;
    use Queueable;
    use SerializesModels;

    /**
     * The PDF we are processing.
     */
    protected Pdf $pdf;

    /**
     * Create a new processor instance for the PDF.
     */
    public function __construct(Pdf $pdf)
    {
        /**
         * This is a resource heavy job. Let's make sure that it is
         * processed evenly across all of our worker servers...
         */
        $this->onQueue(Worker::bestPick());

        $this->pdf = $pdf;
    }

    /**
     * Run the job.
     */
    public function handle(): void
    {
        // Job logic here...
    }
}
```

With this approach, the ProcessPdfJob will always be distributed evenly across multiple servers that are running Horizon. The Worker class I defined currently only supports the 'auto' balance strategy:

```
'worker' => [
    'worker-supervisor' => [
        'connection' => 'redis',
        'queue' => [env('WORKER_QUEUE')],
        'balance' => 'auto',
        'maxProcesses' => 10,
        'maxJobs' => 0,
        'memory' => 512,
        'tries' => 3,
        'nice' => env('WORKER_NICE', 0),
        'timeout' => 600,
        'sleep' => env('WORKER_SLEEP', 3),
    ],
],
```

[image: Horizon Workload]

As you can see in my Horizon Workload screenshot, I have three "worker" servers that all the logic I outlined applies to. My approach currently does not factor in server CPU usage or the current amount of jobs the server is running but I believe the WorkloadRepository class provides some of that data so modifying my Worker class to take that into account shouldn't be too difficult.